# Webview not receiving post message data from web

Tags: react-native, vue.js, react-native-webview

I am loading a Vue web app under react native web view. once i click on a button in web view. it needs to get detected in react native . is there any possibilities for that
?

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`window.postMessage("Click in Vue");` on button click in `Vue js` to post a message form `html` page to `react-native`

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

You can get this message in `Webview` component like this:

```
<WebView
   onMessage={(message) => this.onMessage(message)}
/>
```

In the `onMessage` method you can get data like this:

```
onMessage(message) {
   console.log(message.nativeEvent.data);
}
```

**Update**

It seems that `react-native-webview` has changed the way it calls postMessage so now you should do it like: `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Click in Vue");`

Read more [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

Comment: @PragadishWaran can you please check the updated answer